# Apache redirect directory to subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I'm attempting to get around some Cross Origin issues on IE11 and iOS by masking a subdomain as a directory

i.e.

I want `example.com/cdn/` to actually load `cdn.example.com/`

I've kind of got it working with

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/cdn/(.*)$ http://cdn.example.com/$1
```

But in the browser the redirect happens and it still shows `http://cdn.example.com` rather than leaving it as `example.com/cdn/`

Any way to achieve this!?

Comment: A redirect is the wrong approach. Either you proxy the requests to the subdomain or you do it the right way and allow the subdomain for cross origin requests by adding the proper headers.

Comment: Hmm thanks could you enlighten me on either of those options? I think I have added the proper headers but it's still getting blocked in IE <Edge and iOS.  This is another approach I thought I'd try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) to proxy the requests from the directory through to the actual domain:

```
ProxyRequests         Off
ProxyPreserveHost     On

ProxyPass             /cdn           http://cdn.example.com
ProxyPassReverse      /cdn           http://cdn.example.com
```

This has to be put in the actual apache config, it doesn't work in a .htaccess file.

Note that by proxying the requests like this you are rendering the advantages of a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) useless. The header solution in [my other answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/802728/apache-redirect-directory-to-subdomain/802732#802732) is preferable over this.

Comment: This is working.. but it means not using the CDN on the scenarios where I'm having problems (IE11 and iOS)

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the responses your server provides.

You can to this either in your scripts (PHP or whatever you run on the server) or you can do this in the .htaccess file using [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html):

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://cdn.example.com"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: ...without having to _mask_ the subdomain.

Comment: This is without masking. You are masking it if you use the proxy solution.

Comment: Hmm yeah that makes sense - it's just not making any difference at the moment, I still get loads of security errors when I try and load video from the cdn into a WebGL renderer on IE11 or iOS browsers

Comment: Question - if this is coming via the Java Server (Spring) would the .htaccess still work or do I need to use something like this via Spring?

Comment: Both should work.